# sending a string to another jsp file inside href

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need to send a string to another jsp file from a jsp file by using href.Here is my code

```
 <td>${fn:escapeXml(drugtarget.properties.drug)}</td>
  <td><a href="/list.jsp">Show Info</a></td>
```

I want to send this "${fn:escapeXml(drugtarget.properties.drug)}" to list.jsp file. Thank you

Ok I sent it like this

```
  <c:forEach items="${drugtargets}" var="drugtarget">
<tr>
  <td>${fn:escapeXml(drugtarget.properties.drug)}</td>
  <td><a href="/list.jsp?value=${fn:escapeXml(drugtarget.properties.drug)}">Show Info</a></td>
</tr>
```

Now in list.jsp file I want to display the value. By the way using JSTL in list.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value in list.jsp  try as

```
${param.value}
```

Comment: Giving this error: Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, &lt;%=, &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here.